# Sum of higher Whitehead products

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, whitehead-product

For a CW-complex $X$ and homotopy classes $[f_i] \in \pi_{l_i}(X)$ for $1 \leq i \leq s$, where $s \geq 2$, the higher Whitehead product is defined to be the set

$$[f_1,...,f_s] := \{[\rho \circ \phi] \; | \; \phi \in \omega\} \subseteq \left[\overset{s}{\underset{i=1}{\LARGE{*}}} S^{l_i -1}, X  \right]$$

where $\omega$ denotes the set of homotopy extensions of the map $\bigvee f_i: \bigvee_{i=1}^s S^{l_i} \rightarrow X$ to the fat-wedge $FW(S^{l_1},...,S^{l_s})$, and $$\rho: \overset{s}{\underset{i=1}{\LARGE{*}}} S^{l_i -1} = \bigcup_{i=1}^s D^{l_1} \times ... \times S^{l_i -1} \times ... \times D^{l_s} \longrightarrow FW(S^{l_1},...,S^{l_s})$$
denotes the map obtained by taking the product of maps identifying $\partial D^{l_i}$ to the basepoint.

In general, the higher Whitehead product may be empty, and may contain multiple elements. If a higher Whitehead product is non-empty and contains exactly one element, it is said to have trivial indeterminacy. One may define an addition on higher Whitehead products by taking all pairwise sums of elements. In the case that the products in question have trivial indeterminacy, this operation coincides with the usual addition in $\pi_*(X)$. However, in the case of non-trivial indeterminacy, the resulting set is not necessarily itself a higher Whitehead product.

Has a sum of higher Whitehead products been studied? Does there exist a notion such that the resulting set is itself a higher Whitehead product?